# Algebra involving operator of x and p

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics

For operators x and p in QM with $p= {h\over i}{d \over dx} $, how can I find the combination of operator such as
$$(xp-px)^2 $$ or $$(x+p)(x-p) $$
Can I just expand them by using normal algebra such as
$$(ab-ba)^2=a^2b^2+b^2a^2-abba-baab $$
$$ (a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the commutator $[x,p]=i\hbar.$ This can be shown by
$$
(px)f = p(xf) 
= -i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}(xf) 
= -i\hbar(f+xf')
= -i\hbar f + x(-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}f) 
\\
= -i\hbar f + x(pf)
= -i\hbar f + (xp)f,
$$
so that
$$
[x,p]f = (xp-px)f
= (xp)f - (px)f
= i\hbar f
$$
for every smooth function $f$ which means that $[x,p]=i\hbar.$

Then,
$$
(xp-px)^2 = [x,p]^2 = (i\hbar)^2 = -\hbar^2
$$
and
$$
(x+p)(x-p) = x^2+px-xp-p^2 = (x^2-p^2)-(xp-px) = (x^2-p^2)-i\hbar.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You kind of have the right idea with your examples, but there are mistakes. Remember however that operator multiplication is actually function composition, so $AB$ should really be viewed as the operator defined by $f\mapsto A(B(f))$. To make sense of operators, they should be thought of as acting on functions. Because of this connection to function composition, you cannot conclude that $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2$ in general. It should actually be $a^2 - ab + ba - b^2$, meaning that this is only equal to $a^2 - b^2$ if $a$ and $b$ commute (i.e. $ab = ba$ which is not in general true for operators). So for instance,

\begin{align}
(xp - px)f(x) &= \bigg(x\bigg(-i\frac{d}{dx}\bigg) - \bigg(-i\frac{d}{dx}\bigg)x\bigg)f(x) \\
&= -i x\frac{df}{dx} + i \frac{d}{dx}(xf) \\
&= -ixf'(x) + ixf'(x) + i f(x) \\
&= i f(x)
\end{align}

Thus $xp-px$ is really the same as multiplication by $i$. Can you take care of the examples in your post?

---

There's a connection to polynomials in two variables that can be made if I recall correctly. You can think of this as $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle xy-yx = i\rangle$. The notation might be slightly wrong but you think about the ring of polynomials in two variables quotiented by the ideal $xy-yx = i$.